Ignite Monitoring using controlscript
I am running Ignite as a Java app - using IgniteConfiguration. In this version I don't see control.sh, it is a regular Java installable.
For cases like this, how do I achieve or get the control.sh way for monitoring? -> https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/tools/control-script

Most of the control.sh call have counterparts in the Java API. What are you looking for in particular?

@VladimirPligin - I am looking for an alternate for Visor.
We moved from Apache Ignite 2.10 version to 2.16 version. And post 2.15 Ignite version the Visor has no alternative. So looking for an equivalent tool.

In the normal deployment of Ignite / GridGain if you expand the deployment directory you will see a bin folder (directory) under the main deployment folder. This is where the control.sh script will be found. If you do not have the binary distribution then you would either have to get it and deploy it or look to things like JMX for monitoring and any possible change operations you might be able to make via JMX. Hope that helps.

Thank you for the response.
Looking for a programmatic way of accessing the control script options. Since, the deployment is via a Java app, I don't see the /bin folder.
